# How to use --command-line-file or --command-line options in gem5 FS mode?

Tags: gem5, node.js-fs

I am trying to test a series of benchmarks on gem5 in FS mode, but it's wasting time to launch os, connect terminal and input the command line. Is there any way to run benchmarks automatically? And who konws how to input the command when I launch the os. There are some options may helps in Options.py file, such as --command-line and --command-line-file in addFSOptions() function, but I don't know how to use them. I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me an example.

I am trying to test a series of benchmarks on gem5 in FS mode, but it's wasting time to launch os, connect terminal and input the command line. Is there any way to run benchmarks automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Fully simulating an OS boot is an inherently task, and this latency will be similar in your benchmark simulation. A couple of things might help, though.

I recommend setting a checkpoint for immediately post OS boot, but before the interactive terminal loads. You can restore this checkpoint for whatever benchmark you would like and you will not need to wait for the boot procedure when running benchmarks. Then, look into setting up an environment of bootscripts. These scripts are distinct from the memory state, and as such should not require distinct checkpoints.